# IPC key chose 8 bits from st_dev and 16 bits from st_ino

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc

This is a code copy from UNP Richard Stevens

```
   #include "apue.h"                                                                                
   #include <sys/ipc.h>
   int main(int argc,char * argv[])
   {
       struct stat stat_buf;
       if(argc != 2)
           err_quit("usage ftock <pathname>");
       stat(argv[1],&stat_buf);
       printf("st_dev :%08lx, st_info : %08lx ,key :%08x\n",(unsigned long)stat_buf.st_dev,(unsigned long)stat_buf.st_ino,ftok(argv[1],0x57));
   }
```

Output:

```
st_dev :00000803, st_ino : 018e17c3 ,key :570317c3
```

So the key take 8 bit from `id` , 8 bit from `st_dev` and 16 bit from `st_ino`.

I use SUSE gcc .

I know the book is kind of old. new implement had its new method.

Can anyone tell me the principle of  `ftok`  works? And the reason choose more bits from `st_ino`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each inode is distinct for each file on a device. Each device number is unique for each device (partition). Since there are typically vastly more files per device than devices per system, it makes sense to use more bits from `st_ino` than from `st_dev`, if you are trying to reduce the chances of a collision.

Unfortunately, since `ftok` does not guarantee uniqueness, any application using it must be able to tolerate collisions anyway. This makes it more-or-less useless, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

```
key_t
ftok (pathname, proj_id)
     const char *pathname;
     int proj_id;
{
  struct stat64 st;
  key_t key;

  if (__xstat64 (_STAT_VER, pathname, &st) < 0)
    return (key_t) -1;

  key = ((st.st_ino & 0xffff) | ((st.st_dev & 0xff) << 16)
     | ((proj_id & 0xff) << 24));

  return key;
}
```

Here is the source code from glibc 2.17. As you see, it is still the same.